# How to interpret sendto Unix socket message?

Tags: sockets, debugging, sendto

I have a process fall into infinite loop of keep calling sendto function. I can see the parameters of sendto by strace that process, but I don't know how to read the socket message. Any hint for interpreting this message?

```
    sendto(10, "\10\0\n\0\1\20\v\251\273D\0\0\4\0", 14, 0, 
    {sa_family=AF_FILE, path="/temp/test_ipc_msg"}, 22) = -1,
    EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `-xx` and `-e write 10` options for [`strace(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html). That will hopefully make interpreting the payload easier.

The problem though seems to be that the receiving side is not reading. Since [`unix(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) sockets are always reliable, and there is in fact a limit on how many datagrams are held in the kernel (`/proc/sys/net/unix/max_dgram_qlen` on Linux), the sender cannot write to the socket any more.

Comment: Although I still don't know how to read the socket message `\10\0\n\0\1\20\v\251\273D\0\0\4\0`, your answer helped me find the root cause for this issue -- the small socket queue! After enlarging the socket queue, this problem disappeared.